# Gradle cache Task.upToDateWhen is false even though cache key exists

Tags: java, scala, gradle, caching, github-actions

I'm trying to debug a gradle cache issue for a Test task in a Java/Scala project. Here is the command I'm running:

```
./gradlew build --no-daemon --info --stacktrace --build-cache -Dorg.gradle.caching.debug=true
```

The output I get for the task I'm interested in is:

```
Build cache key for task ':kafka-utils:test' is 803214d05e5842edc7b3e239f8fe08da
Task ':kafka-utils:test' is not up-to-date because:
Task.upToDateWhen is false.
... (Tests omitted for brevity)
Stored cache entry for task ':kafka-utils:test' with cache key 803214d05e5842edc7b3e239f8fe08da
```

I can see the artifact being created in the remote build cache but no matter how many times I replay the task it's always going to complain that `Task.upToDateWhen is false.` and rerun the tests. I do not have any particular test configuration that I can find in my gradle configuration files. Now I'm trying to find out where to go from there? How do I get to *why* `Task.upToDateWhen is false`?

Here's my GHA workflow:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    permissions:
      contents: read
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3.13.0
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.8.1
        with:
          cache-read-only: false

      - name: Gradle build
        env:
          ARTIFACTORY_USER: xxx
          ARTIFACTORY_KEY: xxx
        run: ./gradlew build --no-daemon --info --stacktrace --build-cache -Dorg.gradle.caching.debug=true
```

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question as text. Are you observing this behavior in the same workflow run, subsequent runs on the same branch, or unrelated branches?

Comment: Caching doesn't work even though the cache key is the same both on subsequent runs on the same branch and unrelated branches